# How can I build standalone test binary to run under a debugger?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to package up a specific unit test into an executable binary that I can run myself under a debugger.

How can I do this with cargo?

Comment: Rust's tests _are_ standalone executables. You can find them in `target/debug` (or `target/release`). `cargo test` is just a wrapper that lists and execute each of them individually.

Comment: I didn't see it when I went into that directory, but it turns out I missed it because of the name. It was literally in front of my face when I ran the tests: `Running target/debug/deps/mpsc_test-273c365c039107cd`

Comment: The question linked as a duplicate is exactly what I was trying to find (and I did a lot of searching, for some reason I could not find that one).

Answer (score 13):

Running `cargo test` results in the following output:

```
❯ cargo test
   Compiling mycrate v0.1.0 (mycrate)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.44s
     Running target/debug/deps/mycrate-1a3af12dafb80133

running tests...
```

As you can see by this line:

```
Running target/debug/deps/mycrate-1a3af12dafb80133
```

The test actually *is* a standalone executable, located in `target/debug/deps/`.

You can run the executable directly:

```
❯ ./target/debug/deps/mycrate-1a3af12dafb80133

running tests...
```

You can also build the executable without running the tests with the `no-run` flag:

```
❯ cargo test --no-run
   Compiling mycrate v0.1.0 (mycrate)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.41s
```

Comment: `cargo build` now has a parameter `--test [<name>]`, which builds a test binary with the specified set of tests.